# variable in viewController for ARC

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

my app is built on `UINavigationViewController`, when my app is going to segue to other `UIViewController` on top of the present `UIViewController`. the method of `prepare(for:sender)` will be called before segueing to next `UIViewController`.

I am wondering when I implement overriding `prepare(for:sender)`, for example:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toNextVC", let vc = segue.destination as? NextViewController {
        vc.session = self.session // session is class.
    } 
}
```

so, in `NextViewController`, if `session` is a variable of class, thus, if i need to mark `unowned` for `session` in `NextViewController`?

as `nextViewController` may be removed and go back the former view controller.

Comment: Nope. Actually, the reference count is just one, so no problem is created.

Comment: as i know if i assign self.session to vc.session. ARC should count it as 2.

Comment: @Milan Nosáľ is right when using `UINavigationViewController` we expect any property to be alive until all the `ViewControllers` from the stack are popped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NextViewController` can own the `session` variable (thus increasing its ARC). When you pop the controller (you go back from it), it will get deallocated and its reference to `session` will be automatically deleted, thus decreasing its ARC back.

The potential problem might occur, if the `session` variable will get a reference to the `NextViewController`, thus creating a retain cycle. Then the `NextViewController` won't be deallocated (because its ARC > 0), and that would prevent decreasing ARC for `session`. Such a cycle you would have to break by using `unowned` or `weak`.

Comment: so you mean i should use weak or unowned for `session` in `NextViewController` , right?

Comment: is there a reference from `session` to `NextViewController`?

Comment: if not, then do not use `weak` nor `unowned`, use normal strong reference. I believe in your case there is not the reference from `session` to `NextViewController`, only from `NextViewController` to `session`, and therefore I would NOT use a `weak` nor `unowned` keyword